# Django with S3 staticfiles optimization

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, compression

I am trying to optimize my staticfiles using django with S3. I am using django compressor to compress and cache js and css files. 
Here are my settings :

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = secret_key
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='mybucketname'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

S3_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' %AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + "media/"
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + "static/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "admin/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static","static_dirs"),
     #'/var/www/static/',
 )
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=86400',
}

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static","static_root")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'lafabrique.settings.s3utils.CachedS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE =    'lafabrique.settings.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'lafabrique.settings.s3utils.CachedS3BotoStorage'
COMPRESS_URL = S3_URL
```

and in another file :

```
class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage")()
    def save(self, name, content):
         name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
         self.local_storage._save(name, content)
         return name
```

What I don't understand is that when I test my page on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/, google still tells me that I should use gzip and cache on my static files... 
Also in my amazon http response I get : Cache-Control:max-age=0 ... ( actual website is lafabrique.io, just in case)

Does somebody know what I did wrong ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Django-storages? Try adding this to your settings:

```
AWS_IS_GZIPPED = True
GZIP_CONTENT_TYPES = (
 'text/css',
 'application/javascript',
 'application/x-javascript',
 'text/javascript'
)
```

It looks like you're using gzipped storage on your local machine, but not for the file that you upload to S3.

For the caching issue, try the solution here: [Trouble setting cache-cotrol header for Amazon S3 key using boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539880/trouble-setting-cache-cotrol-header-for-amazon-s3-key-using-boto)

Comment: Thank you SMX, you solved my GZIP problem ! But I did not found a correct answer about caching in your link

Comment: Try copying the settings line from the first answer of the linked page--I was having a similar problem and that fixed it for me.